# Extract a path from the output of `gem environment` using sed

Tags: regex, sed, rubygems, extract

Executing `gem environment` returns the following output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Using `sed`, how do I extract specifically the `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` value to retrieve `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pipe your output to awk like this:

```
gem environment | awk -F ' *: *' '$1 ~ /EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY/{print $2}'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be really hard to do using `sed`, you'd basically have to delete every line that doesn't contain `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY`, and from the rest delete everything up to the colon.

```
gem environment | sed '/EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY/!d;s/^.*: //'
```

I would recommend `awk` for that.

```
gem environment | awk -F': *' '/EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY/ {print $2}'
```

or `grep`:

```
gem environment |  grep -Po 'EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: \K.*'
```